# Call JavaScript function from C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

**JQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {            
     function btnekle(){
         $('#icerik-right').animate({
             scrollTop: $('#icerik-right').offset().top + $('#icerik-right')[0].scrollHeight
         }, 2000);
         return false;
      } 
    });
```

**C#**

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "script", "btnekle();", true);
```

Where can I make mistakes ??

Comment: What is the output HTML? Any exceptions or errors?

Comment: When I click the button does not work

Comment: *scope*.  `btnekle` only appears inside doc.ready, so can't be called outside it.

Comment: "*When I click the button does not work*" - what button?  There's no button or even reference to a button in your question!

Comment: I pressure button , c # code does not work is trying .Jquery code work

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for ready function you can directly write like this

```
function btnekle(){
         alert('Called');
         $('#icerik-right').animate({
             scrollTop: $('#icerik-right').offset().top + $('#icerik-right')[0].scrollHeight
         }, 2000);
         return false;
      }
```

I suggest you try to debug by putting `alert` for debugging (to check function called or not) or try to debug things with help of developer tool bar .